# Automatically delete row in sheet 2 if stock number is the same and if date entered in sheet1?

Tags: vba, excel

Hello:) I need excel to automatically (thus vba would be preferrable) delete a  row in Sheet2 if column D (stock number) for that row in Sheet2 matches the G column for any row in sheet 1 and if column AY's value for that row in sheet1 is a date. does anyone know how to do this? please let me know if i was unclear i would be happy to clarify further.
thank you so much, elias

Comment: _thus vba would be preferrable although i am also open to using a macro_ ... using a macro means using VBA :)

Comment: Record a macro while you're doing this action you described above; hence, with the output code, make some modifications in a way that your procedure becomes dynamic (and not dependent on absolute references, as it will come out the first time). Once you've done this, should you get stuck on a specific point, don't hesitate to come back asking a precise question.

Comment: I think you should start be researching "how do delete a row using VBA".  Once you have that down, look up "how to find a number from one worksheet on another worksheet".  Now practice combining both of those steps.  After you've mastered that, add in the third requirement and you're done!  Should you get jammed up on one part, please post what you've tried..what worked, what didn't, etc.  Someone will be more than happy to help you with that one part.  I wouldn't wait for someone to do the whole thing for you (well, not without sharing whatever compensation you'll be getting...)

Answer (score 0):

I would read the data up from sheet one and then look through the second sheet for matches. You will need to add a reference for the adodb recordset. In the VBA IDE on the tools pulldown menu select references. Select "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library".

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Activate

'Add fields to your recordset for storing data.
With rs
    .Fields.Append "Row", adInteger
    .Fields.Append "StockNumber", adChar, 50
    '.Fields.Append "DateAY", adChar, 50
    .Fields.Append "DateAY", adDate
    .Open
End With

lRow = 1

'Loop through and record what is in the columns
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("Row").Value = lRow
    rs.Fields("StockNumber").Value = ws.Range("G" & lRow).Value
    rs.Fields("DateAY").Value = ws.Range("AY" & lRow).Value
    rs.Update

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop

If rs.EOF = False Then
    rs.MoveFirst
End If

'Switch to the second worksheet
Set ws = Nothing
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
ws.Activate

'Loop through the second sheet looking at the stock numbers.
lRow = 1
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

    rs.Filter = ""
    rs.Filter = "StockNumber='" & ws.Range("D" & lrow).Value & "'"
    if rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
         'We have a match, now check if there is a date.
         If trim(rs.Fields("DateAY")) <> "" then
              'It has a date, delete the current row
              ws.Rows(lRow).entireRow.Delete
              lRow = lRow - 1
         End if
    End if

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop
End sub
```

I'm not sure if the row needs incremented when you delete a row since the next row will now be your current row.  You may need to add

```
lRow = lRow - 1
```

right after you delete the current row.  That will bring it back a row and then the normal increment will effectively set it back to the current row.

Comment: thank you so much for your comment matthew and for your comment sous. i selected the data objects library 2.8 however, i keep getting a run time error which says that the active method of range class failed on the first instance of ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate. do you know how to fix this? thanks :3

Comment: is it in the second loop?  I do see a place we need to add  lRow = 1 right before the first loop See above edit.

Comment: I see it now.  We need to add ws.Activate after the Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") line.  Add it after the Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") also.  But from my last comment you do need to add lRow = 1 before the second loop.

Comment: thanks again. it seems close to working but i am still getting a type mismatch error on this line:rs.Filter = "StockNumber='" & ws.Range("D" & lrow).Value & "'"    im sorry for not mentioning this earlier but the stock number has letters in it as well. i thought the errror might be the result of appending the stock number field as ad integer. i tried changing it to adVarChar and ad Char and it still didnt work. is this the source of the error? thank you so much

Comment: Ahh, no problem.  Change .Fields.Append "StockNumber", adinteger  to   .Fields.Append "StockNumber", adChar, 50  .  50 being the lenght of the string that may come as a stock number.  You can adjust it.  I alsow changed The dateAY to  adChar, 50.  You can play with using a date on that one.   That would be adDate if you find you need to go that route.  Dates get tricky to use though.  You might want to stay with adChar

Comment: LAST QUESTION :'( the program seems to be working well. thank you so much! however, it is not deleting all the entries in one click event. (i should mention that i set lrow for sheet 1 as lRow=9 and in sheet2 as lRow=20 because that is the first row where the data appears in each sheet. idk if that is the cause of the error).

Comment: That should be just fine.  The lRow is where the loop will start from so you have set it correctly.  What do you mean that it isn't deleting all the entries?

Comment: I think you are seeing what i initially thought would happen.  We need to add  lRow = lRow - 1  after the entirerow.delete line.  Let me know if that works and mark this answer as accepted.   And we need to change the line If rs.Fields("DateAY") <> "" then to If trim(rs.Fields("DateAY")) <> "" then   adding the trim() function.